# Increase Vim's Scrolling Speed

Tags: vim, macvim

I don't like the way MacVim has such a slow scrolling speed, ( Was faster on gVim, Ubuntu ), is there a way to speed it up ?

Comment: By scrolling speed you mean the number of lines when you issue a Ctrl-F/PageDown? If it is not, please provide more details.

Comment: I think this question is perfectly appropriate for Stack Overflow (from FAQ: "question generally covers... software tools commonly used by programmers"; I'd say vim qualifies). I had the same question. Using the arrow keys or j/k to scroll in MacVim (or default vim) is really slow compared to Ubuntu. The solution is to go to System Preferences->Keyboard and the set "Key Repeat Rate" to the fastest setting; that'll feel much more comfortable. Mac OS's key repeat rate is just a lot slower by default than Ubuntu.

Comment: @David Vim' a text editor, just like Notepad on Windows. It *can* be used for simple coding but however these questions are not on-topic.

Comment: Sorry, @cybermonkey, I don't know what you're trying to say. 

"These questions" -- whose questions? the original poster's question?

"are not on-topic" -- for what? for StackOverflow? as a comment?

"like Notepad on Windows" -- how's that related to slow scrolling speed in MacOS?

Comment: @David Vim is a Linux command line text editor.

Comment: @cybermonkey And gvim is a GUI text editor. Both gvim and console vim are affected by MacOS's default key repeat speed. Do you have a point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean mouse scrolling speed (since keyboard scrolling is welldefined and shouldn't vary across platforms/versions unless you modified your .vimrc)

From http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#scroll-mouse-wheel

> You can modify the default behavior by mapping the keys.  For example, to make
>     the scroll wheel move one line or half a page in Normal mode: >
>
> ```
>     :map <ScrollWheelUp> <C-Y>
>     :map <S-ScrollWheelUp> <C-U>
>     :map <ScrollWheelDown> <C-E>
>     :map <S-ScrollWheelDown> <C-D>
> ```
>
> You can also use Alt and Ctrl modifiers.

Comment: Is there a way to speed up the scrolling when pressing `j` or `k` ?